# Controlling a headless torrent server via transmission

Tags: raspbian, networking, ssh, p2p

I'm running transmission-daemon on a Raspberry Pi running headless Raspbian. I can SSH into it fine, and the FTP server on it runs without a hitch, but I can't use the terminal interface for Transmission to control it. Running:

```
$ transmission-remote -m
$ transmission-remote localhost -m
$ sudo transmission-remote -m
```

All give the following error:

> Unexpected response: 401: Unauthorized User: deflate, gzip

Any ideas? Or am I using the wrong command? I want to be able to see active torrents, add more, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transmission-daemon has a web interface.
If you want a pure command line interface, use transmission-cli
Otherwise if you want to use transmission-remote, you'll need to modify `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json` and modify this line -
`"rpc-authentication-required": true,` and make the true a false

Comment: I changed `"rpc-authentication-required": true` to false, restarted the server, and I still can't connect or see server stats.

Comment: transmission-daemon is a bit funny, If you restart the server, it will overwrite the configuration file.  After you modify the configuration file, run this command - `killall -HUP transmission-daemon`

Comment: I'm still getting the error and I checked to make sure the config file is persisting.

Comment: Can you paste the config file somewhere ?

Comment: I tried re-installing and following all the instructions again and it works now, but there's no authentication. If someone has my IP address, couldn't they use transmission?

Comment: If transmission is behind a router, they won't be able to access it unless you forward the listening port. Otherwise if it's not behind a router then you can simply block access to the port with iptables

Comment: I was going to port forward 9091 so I could access it with the Transmission client instead of SSHing to manage torrents.

Comment: Tranmission client being transmission-remote ?

Comment: No, Transmission-Qt. I was able to port forward and Transmission-Qt works fine with authentication enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep `"rpc-authentication-required": true` for security reasons, you can supply the username and password with the auth flag, e.g. `transmission-daemon -m --auth username:password`.

It's quite possible that the server could be reachable by others, depending on how things are setup. I would recommend keeping auth on if you're not sure - it can't hurt.